# Ошибка при получении почты

Tags: python-3.x, imap

Ошибка при считывании вот код:

```
# coding: utf8
import imaplib,email

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.ru')
M.login(nick, pass)
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, '(FROM "from@mail.ru")')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC3501)')
    raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    print (raw.get_payload(None,True))
M.close()
M.logout()
```

Вот ошибка:

```
FETCH command error: BAD [b'[PARSE] Range parse error']
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возвращается не библиотекой, а сервером, поскольку он не может разобрать параметр команды `fetch` протокола `IMAP`.
А зачем вы передаёте `'(RFC3501)'`, какой смысл в это вкладываете?
Я мало знаком с `python` и ещё меньше с его библиотеками, но согласно описанию [протокола](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-54) возможным значением параметра для получения тела сообщения является строка `'RFC822'`.

Comment: Я просто лазил по просторам интернета в одном посте увидел что надо сменить

Comment: Что надо сменить? Вы либо ответ примите, либо дайте свой, хотя бы в виде полного комментария к своему вопросу.

Comment: 'RFC822' на RFC3501

Comment: А с 'RFC822' тоже ошибку получаете?

Comment: Да, с первым и вторым.. это зависит из-за того какой параметр я передам в M.search(), когда передаю ALL - все нормально, когда FROM вот такая ошибка

Comment: Проверьте, что возвращает запрос `search`. По протоколу результатом должно быть множество писем (список UID или индексов), удовлетворяющих условию. С `ALL`, понятное дело, у вас что-то находится. А если по условию `FROM` сервер ничего не нашёл, то возможно, что в цикл вход происходит, но с неправильными параметрами для `FETCH`.